# React redux reducer as UseEffect dependency causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am just diving deep into React. But the *useEffect* React hook still got me confused. I know that I can pass dependencies as an array to it to control rendering of the component. I have used props and local state to do and it works.

What's got me still confused is when I pass redux reducer as a dependency. It causes an infinite loop of rendering the component.

#### *users* component

```
const usersComp = () => {
    const users = useSelector(state => state.users);

    useEffect(
        // Fetch users and update users state
        useDispatch().dispatch(getUsers)
    ,[users]) // <-- Causes an infinite loop!!

    if(users.length){
        return( users.map(user => <p>{user}</p>))
    }
}
```

#### getUsers Redux Thunk function

```
export async function getUsers(dispatch, getState) {
    fetch(endpoint)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(users => {
            dispatch({type: GET_USERS, payload: users})
        }).catch(err => console.error("Error: ", err));
}
```

#### *users* reducer

```
export default function usersReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case GET_USERS : {
            return [...state, action.payload]
        }
    }
}
```

From what I understand, *users* start off as an empty array, and then gets filled with data from an API call. So *useEffect* should fire twice; when the component has just mounted and then when users state changes from the API call. So what's causing the infinite loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `users` from the `useEffect` dependency, because you want to fetch users when component mounts, not **each time** the `users` is changed.

```
useEffect(
    useDispatch().dispatch(getUsers)
,[]) // Now, it will fetch users ONLY ONCE when component is mounted
```

Explanation:

```
// Case 1
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Mounted") // Printed only once when component is mounted
}, [])

// Case 2
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("users changed") // Printed each time when users is changed
}, [users])
```

So, if you do `fetch` in *Case 2*, it will *change* `users` which will retrigger the hook which will `fetch` the users again which changes the `users` and causes the hook to retrigger → This is an **infinite loop**.

#### Update:

Why is `state.users` getting changed (in this code), as detected by `useEffect`, even when values of `state.users` are "SAME" (Same values)?

Whenever `GET_USERS` action is dispatched, reducer returns **new** state (`{ ...state, users: action.payload })`. It does so even when value of `action.payload` holds the same value of users.
This is why `useEffect` receives **new** users array. (They do shallow comparison.)

Note that, `[1, 2,3] is not equal to [1, 2,3]` i.e.  `[1, 2,3] === [1, 2,3]` returns false.

If for some reason, you want to return the **same** redux state, do `return state` in the reducer. This is often what we do in the `default` case of `switch` of reducer.

Comment: Thanks @Ajeet this solves the issue. However, I want some additional explanation about users state. From the Users Component perspective,  state.users is the same value with each subsequent re-trigger. I have not updated or removed any users yet. Maybe I am not understanding Redux State very well.

Comment: This makes sense now. Thanks for the elaborate response.